# Redux children missing in prop validation

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have below class where i am getting props validation error when i run my lint.

```
`children` is missing in prop validation react/prop-types

// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
// Import your own reducer
import reducer from '../reducer'

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

is there any way that i can fix this other than excluding this in lint settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `propTypes` to the `Wrapper` component.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

Wrapper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: How can i add this as `Wrapper` is inside the function.?

Comment: @rakeeee Sorry, not sure if I understand your question. You can add the proptypes after the function definition.

Comment: I mean how to check Proptype as `Wrapper` function is inside the `render` function?

Comment: @rakeeee As I mentioned in my previous reply, you can add it next to the `Wrapper` function definition.